# How to generate c# wrappers for QuickFix from source?

Tags: c#, wrapper, quickfix

I cloned the project from here : https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/tree/master/src

and tryied to execute the scripts spec/generate.bat or GeneratorNET.rb but I cant get the whole .cs files in order to build the quickfix_net.dll c# wrapper properly.

Anyone knows how to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: where you ever able to generate the .tt files ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[There does exist a C# version of Quickfix -> QuickFIX/N.. Why do you want to reinvent the wheel again, unless you have very specific needs to do so. Or did I miss something ?](http://www.quickfixn.org/)

Comment: QuickFIX/N is not matured yet. I was wondering if the wrapped version was not more stable. But you are right, I checked the pros/cons and I will contribute to QuickFix/N, and so, use this one.